# Macbook air '14 adapter on new Macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, charger

I have a MacBook Air from 2014. In its charger, I attach the following component (a).
[image]

I got a new MacBook Pro 16 but unfortunately it came with (what I presume to be) an american adapter (b) as you can see below.
[image]

Can I use adapter (a) on my MacBook Pro 6 charger with no issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the plugs are designed to be interchangeable. (In fact, Apple sells a 'World Travel kit' that just consists of all the different plugs.)

It's not really an 'adaptor', as such: just a switchable part at the end of the cable.

The three-pronged plug is a UK power plug.